# How to configure local hosts in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost, vhosts

I have made changes in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       dev
```

After uncommented line in http.conf:

`Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

And last I made changes in `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

This is full code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin someone@example.org
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev"
    ServerName dev
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.loc-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.loc-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

After rebooting Apache and trying open URL `http://dev` I get nothing.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The `ServerAdmin` directive takes an _email address_ as argument, not a host name or domain.

Comment: I suggest you start monitoring your log files. That should point out any potential issue.

Comment: Sorry, there is email, not domain name, think problem is another

Comment: `popgmail.com` certainly is _not_ an email address. If you want to disguise your real address, then please use something like `someone@example.org` instead. Thanks.

Comment: How to specify full path to log files? I mean where they should be located?

Comment: Well, just specify an absolute path, so a path starting with a slash like you did for the `DocumentRoot`. Either place them in the system logs folder or something like `/Applications/MAMP/logs/...`. It does not really matter. But you need to _look into_ them!

Comment: I use MAMP, and seem problem is in port :8888 is it required to set in URL?

Comment: Your configuration names port 80 which is the standard. You want to compare that to your `Listen` command in your configuration.

Comment: How to configure that dont enter  port again? only local domain name as `dev` instead `dev:8888`?

Comment: I wrote what you need to know in my last comment. Didn't you read that?

Comment: Also please note that the question on how to configure the port the server listens on is documented.